# Spring Integration Web Service - Jaxb2Marshaller - How I can use SAX Parser?

Tags: jaxb, spring-integration, sax, spring-ws

I am using `Jaxb2Marshaller` with Spring Integration. I have an inbound gateway web service, when someone call it, it will auto parse into JAXB generated classes.

But when I debug into the source, I see `Jaxb2Marshaller` using DOM. I thought it would use SAX as for binding XML data into Java object, SAX is faster. Why `Jaxb2Marshaller` use DOM by default ? How can I configure it to use SAX ?

As I checked the document

> The
>   unmarshaller requires an instance of Source. If the message payload is not an instance of Source,
>   conversion will be attempted. Currently String, File and org.w3c.dom.Document payloads are
>   supported. Custom conversion to a Source is also supported by injecting an implementation of a
>   SourceFactory.
>   Note
>   If a SourceFactory is not set explicitly, the property on the UnmarshallingTransformer will
>   by default be set to a DomSourceFactory

About SourceFactory

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/xml/source/SourceFactory.html

We can see that currently, it only has `DomSourceFactory` and `StringSourceFactory`. There is no `SaxSourceFactory`.

So we can't use SAX with `Jaxb2Marshaller`, right ?

Will it have `SaxSourceFactory` in the future ? or never ?

The weird thing is when I check `Jaxb2Marshaller` , I see the code already handle SAX

```
XMLReader xmlReader = null;
    InputSource inputSource = null;

    if (source instanceof SAXSource) {
        SAXSource saxSource = (SAXSource) source;
        xmlReader = saxSource.getXMLReader();
        inputSource = saxSource.getInputSource();
    }
    else if (source instanceof StreamSource) {
        StreamSource streamSource = (StreamSource) source;
        if (streamSource.getInputStream() != null) {
            inputSource = new InputSource(streamSource.getInputStream());
        }
        else if (streamSource.getReader() != null) {
            inputSource = new InputSource(streamSource.getReader());
        }
        else {
            inputSource = new InputSource(streamSource.getSystemId());
        }
    }
```

So, the final question is CAN I configure use Spring Integration Web Service with JAXB with SAX ? Am I missed something?

Here is my configurations:

```
<ws:inbound-gateway id="inbound-gateway" request-channel="RequestChannel" reply-channel="ResponseChannel" 
        marshaller="marshaller"        unmarshaller="marshaller"  />
<int:channel id="RequestChannel" />
<int:channel id="ResponseChannel" />

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="com.example.webservice.api"/>
</bean>
```

Thank you and best regards,

Nha Nguyen

Comment: @lexicore Could you help me on this :-)

Comment: sax is not faster... sax is often slower because of all the extra app logic you need to custom implement...

Comment: Looks like you have some misunderstanding. You show `<ws:inbound-gateway>`, but talk about `UnmarshallingTransformer`. The first one fully delegates to Spring WS `MarshallingUtils.unmarshal()`

Comment: @Artem  Bilan,  I mean in <ws:inbound-gateway>, we can configure an unmarshaller, but we can not configure which technology (SAX or DOM or StAX) that unmarshaller will use. 

The document says that we can inject a SourceFactory and Spring Integration will use it, but there is no SaxSourceFactory yet (just have DomSourceFactory, StringSourceFactory) . So how we can force an JAXB Unmarshaller use SAX ?

Comment: Are you sure that doc is about WS? Show me, please, a sample when you inject `SourceFactory` into `<int-ws:inbound-gateway>`. Why my answer isn't sufficient for you?

Comment: The unmarshaller requires an instance of Source. If the message payload is not an instance of Source, conversion will be attempted. Currently String, File and org.w3c.dom.Document payloads are
supported. Custom conversion to a Source is also supported by injecting an implementation of a SourceFactory.
Note If a SourceFactory is not set explicitly, the property on the UnmarshallingTransformer will by default be set to a DomSourceFactory.

( it is on page 451 (472/577) of Spring Integration Reference document)

- Yes look like I have some misunderstanding.

Comment: I think ( still think):

In <ws:inbound-gateway> tag, there is attribute named "unmarshaller". I think it is the same meaning with UnmarshallingTransformer. Is it correct ?

Comment: Oh it is not correct, but does related 1:1 as said in doc:

An UnmarshallingTransformer allows an XML Source to be unmarshalled using implementations of the Spring OXM Unmarshaller.

So in order to force Unmarshaller use the technology you want, you need to have a correct UnmarshallingTransformer  (yes, your answer below explain that. It has getPayLoad() method which return the Source, and if the Source is SAXSource => unmarshaller will use SAX Parser. If the Source is DOMSource => use DOM)

CLEAR ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to configure `AxiomSoapMessageFactory` bean with the name `MessageDispatcherServlet.DEFAULT_MESSAGE_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME`.

By default it is `SaajSoapMessageFactory` which does exactly this before unmarshalling:

```
public Source getPayloadSource() {
    SOAPElement bodyElement = SaajUtils.getFirstBodyElement(getSaajBody());
    return bodyElement != null ? new DOMSource(bodyElement) : null;
}
```

where Axiom is based on STaX:

```
XMLStreamReader streamReader = getStreamReader(payloadElement);
return StaxUtils.createCustomStaxSource(streamReader);
```

And `class StaxSource extends SAXSource {`

Comment: Yes, I tried to configure and successful ^_^. Now JAXB unmarshalling using StAX parser (even better than SAX).

Comment: I guess in order to have SAX Source (so JAXB will call SAXParser), I need to find a third-party library that have getPayloadSource() return a SAXSource ^^

Thank you

Comment: I read many times but don't understand util read again again your answer :-(

IQ limited :D

Comment: Yeah. I think the confuse happened because WS project use the same OXM foundation.

Comment: But, yay, if answer is correct, you should accept to help other people to find the solution easily

Comment: I tried to click the up arrow, but it says that my score is less than 15, so it does not count :-(.  I don't see any button to click "Accept"

Comment: yep ! >.<  IQ limited :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm using WebServiceGatewaySupport classes and tried adding a AxiomSoapMessageFactory as Bean to the application context, until I found out that WebServiceTemplate does not load the WebServiceMessageFactory from the application context. So I ended up with adding a constructor:

```
public class SomeServiceImpl extends WebServiceGatewaySupport implements SomeService {

    public SomeServiceImpl(WebServiceMessageFactory messageFactory) {
        super(messageFactory);
    }
}
```

and building the service myself with a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServicesConfiguration {

    private WebServiceMessageFactory webServiceMessageFactory = new AxiomSoapMessageFactory();

    @Bean
    public SomeService someService() {
        return new SomeServiceImpl(webServiceMessageFactory);
    }
}
```